# error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : ‘x’ and ‘y’ lengths differ"

Tags: r, exploratory-data-analysis

I am trying to extract a few rows from the dataset using R programming to make a new table to perform EDA. df<-cancer[1:205, c(1,2,8,10,15)], RStudio is throwing this error, "error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : ‘x’ and ‘y’ lengths differ". Can anyone explain why am I getting this error? all columns have the same number of rows.

Comment: What do you get from `dim(df)`  ?

Comment: That looks like an error that would be thrown by a plotting function. Are you sure the code you offered is the problem? (If the code failed then there should be no data object in the workspace and `df` should be a function name.